# facebook graph api iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I been listening around that facebook iOS sdk is not functioning properly. Is there a new iOS facebook sdk available? Please suggest if some one has used the facebook iOS sdk and its working fine till now. As I haven't used fb iOS sdk before, it's my first attempt. So Please do share your experience and some tutorial too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working , i tried it last week and its working fine

Comment: Have you used Graph API or just simple FBConnect?

Comment: yes its working, i tried the Ray Wenderlich tutorial using graph API

Comment: Why some one has downvoted it..?
Please before down voting do add a commnet like :   (-1) reason for down voting.

Comment: Yeah Ray is great.. but he is not using the facebook-graph-api ios sdk.. but using the old fbconnect plus graph api